# Exportar e importar .JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-import, exports

**Editado**
Estoy creando una página HTML y javascript para uso local, sin conexión ni uso de live server de Visual Studio Code; evitando así el uso de archivo .JSON o `await fetch()` o similares.

Pensando en `import()` y `export()` podría hacer algo, pero no logro aplicar y usar correctamente. Porque en el HTML solamente cargo mi archivo `main.js` que de lo cual importa todo el contenido de `datos.js`, lo cual contiene un extenso `array` que muestro en DOM.

Si hay otra solución, quisiera saber.

archivo datos.js

```
let datos = [
    {
        ubicacion: {
            nombre: "",
            url: "",
        },
        categoria: {
            nombre: "",
            url: ""
        }
    }
];

exports = {datos};
```

archivo main.js

```
import datos from "datos.js";

datos.forEach( (item) => {
 
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
    <h1>hola</h1>
   `;
                
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las sintaxis para el uso `export` e `import` es la siguiente:

Archivo datos.js

```js
export const datos = [
  {
    ubicacion: {
      nombre: "",
      url: "",
    },
    categoria: {
      nombre: "",
      url: ""
    }
  }
];
```

Archivo main,js

```js
import {datos} from './datos.js'

datos.forEach((item) => {

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
   <h1>hola</h1>
  `;

});
```

---

Más info:

- [MDN > Javascript > export](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)
- [MDN > Javascript > import](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [MDN > Javascript > Módulos Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: En el templete que aplicó con forEach, escribo todo lo que está en datos.js. pero así no me funciona. Por ejemplo: `<h1>${item['categoria'].nombre}</h1>`

Comment: Este código es solamente un ejemplo para la pregunta. No iba poner todo mi código tal cual porque es extenso. Y el error que dice es: `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Comment: En mi HTML normalmente carga el archivo main.js y solamente éste así: `<script src="src/js/main.js"></script>`

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz, ese es el problema te falta agregar `type="module"` al tag `script`. PD: ja... no se de donde saque que se llamaba `prueba.js` ^^

Comment: Ok. Esa parte solucionado y todo hasta aquí. Porque abrí con live server de visual y todo bien. Peeeeeeeeeero, mi problema vuelve al principio: no quiero esto, como si fuera una web en línea. Por eso dejé asínc awai() para cargar archivo JSON. Lo que quiero es todo sin conexión ni nada, porque mi página no está en línea, solo es para uso local